# Echo multiple variables to one div class

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo a user name and a greeting from IF statement i made.

```
<?php
                global $current_user;
                get_currentuserinfo();
                echo get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 64 );
                $hour = date('G');
                if ($hour < 12) {
                    $greeting = 'Good Morning';
              } else if ($hour < 18) {
                    $greeting = 'Good Evening';
              } else {
                    $greeting = 'Good Night';
        }

    echo '<div class="greeting">'.($greeting). , .$current_user->user_login. '</div>';
?>
```

but i'm getting syntax error:

> syntax error, unexpected ','

How can i echo 2 variables into one div?

Comment: Even the syntax-highlighting of this site tells you, whats wrong ;) Which string doesn't look like the other? Hint: It's mentioned in the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comma should be enclosed in a string:

```
echo '<div class="greeting">'.$greeting.' , '.$current_user->user_login. '</div>';
```